# WebIOPi + ESP8266 - Setting up Server/Client communication

Tags: web-server, webiopi, esp8266

I've been working on this project, which consists in using a web page to control RPi's GPIOs and read sensor data via WebIOPI. Everything worked fine, at this point the project is very simple and the documentation on [WebIOPi website](http://webiopi.trouch.com) really helped. Also, if anyone is having trouble with this, I recommend [this tutorial](https://forums.connectedly.com/raspberry-pi-f179/how-controlling-gpio-pins-via-internet-2884/). But I decided to raise the complexity level by doing the exact same thing, except controlling various ESP-01s connected to the server as clients. These ESP-01s have been updated with NodeMCU firmware, in order to be programmed directly and not only used as Wi-Fi modules for some other microcontroller. Also, they can be programmed straight from the Arduino IDE, which really helps.

The thing is: I have no experience at all working with HTTP protocols. There are several examples for both server and client applications on the ESP8266 side, but I can't figure out what to do on the RPi side. I've already been able to connect the ESP-01 to the server on the Pi, but I can't really exchange information between them.(Here is the code that does the connection on the client side, in case anyone asks)

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define       LED0      2

char*         ssid = "SSID";
char*         password = "PASSWORD";

int             ESPServerPort  = 8000;
IPAddress       ESPServer(192,168,0,133);
WiFiClient      client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED0, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("\nSetting I/O Pin Modes ... Done\n");

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
    delay(50);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.println("!--- Connecting To " + WiFi.SSID() + " ---!");

  CheckWiFiConnectivity();

  digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);
  Serial.println("!-- Client Device Connected --!\n");

  Serial.println("Connected To      : " + String(WiFi.SSID()));
  Serial.println("Signal Strenght   : " + String(WiFi.RSSI()) + " dBm");
  Serial.print  ("Server IP Address : ");
  Serial.println(ESPServer);
  Serial.print  ("Server Port Num   : ");
  Serial.println(ESPServerPort);
  Serial.print  ("Device MC Address : ");
  Serial.println(String(WiFi.macAddress()));
  Serial.print  ("Device IP Address : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print  ("\n\n");

  ESPRequest();
}

void loop(){

}


void CheckWiFiConnectivity(){
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
      digitalWrite(LED0, !HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(LED0, !LOW);
      delay(250);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}

void ESPRequest(){

  client.stop();
  Serial.println("!---Connecting to server---!");

  client.connect(ESPServer, ESPServerPort);

  if(client.connected()){
    Serial.println    ("<CONNECTED>\n");
    client.println ("<CONNECTED>");
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to tap into the WebIOPi code files, the ones that do the HTTP heavy-lifting, or if simple changes on my html/javascript code would do the trick. Well... How can I do this?

Help a newbie out guys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone has trouble with this in the future, I figured it out. It turns out the REST API on WebIOPi does all the work, really. You can check this out on [WebIOPi Documentation](http://webiopi.trouch.com/RESTAPI.html). To put it simply: no need to mess around with server configurations, all you need is have your client make the request. In my case, it ended up like this:

```
void loop(){
    HTTPClient http;
    int state;

    Serial.println("!---[HTTP] begin---!\n");
    http.begin("http://192.168.0.133:8000/GPIO/27/value");

    Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if(httpCode > 0) {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            state = payload.toInt();
            Serial.println(payload);
        }
    } 

    else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }

    if(state == 1)
        digitalWrite(LED0, HIGH);
    else
        digitalWrite(LED0, LOW);

    http.end();
    delay(200);
}
```

The http.begin() is set to request the value of GPIO 27. Then, given the state of this GPIO on RPi, the GPIO on ESP8266 is set accordingly.